# How to match all ASCII characters with POSIX regexp

Tags: regex, posix

Is there a way match all ASCII characters with POSIX extended regexp?
`[[:ascii:]]` is not available in POSIX ERE.

Comment: All printable ASCII? I think this famous `[ -~]` will do.

Comment: How is that translated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compose a character class with `[:print:]` *(`[\x20-\x7E]`)* and `[:cntrl:]` 
*(`[\x00-\x1F\x7F]`)*:

```
[[:print:][:cntrl:]]
```

Comment: POSIX character classes are locale dependent, so that may match more than just ASCII.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: In this case, put LANG=POSIX before.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Correct, but is there a way to set my own ranges based on the character codes?